# How to trigger browser to save/ autofill a login form with 3 or more credentials?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a login form that has 3 fields- username, password, and company ID.

Browsers have no problem recognizing the username/ password, and saving/ autofilling them, but they do not recognize the company ID field.

Just to prototype, I've implemented my desired functionality with locaclStorage, but I of course want to do it in a more secure way without localStorage.

I'm working with Vue/vuex.

Much of what I've come across are solutions for autofilling forms, but I think this implementation needs to be different since it is pre-login authentication credentials.

I've looked into the Chrome/browser password manager api's but they seem to *only* handle user/password.

My basic implementation with localStorage:

On successful login, company ID is saved to localStorage:

```
localStorage.setItem('companyId', self.companyId);
```

Then on future logins, login form will be autofilled with the company ID, if one is found in local storage:

```
 if(localStorage.getItem('companyId')){
            self.companyId = localStorage.getItem('companyId')
          }
```

Comment: Could you please share what your form looks like in HTML?

Answer (score 2):

Browsers don't autofill all kinds of form inputs. They actually handle a small amount of values, as documented on this Mozilla documentation [HTML autocomplete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete#values)

For your "company id" field, I'd suggest to use the name `organization-title`, which is supported by the autofill api, for the browser to save it:

```
<input name="organization-title" id="companyId" />
```